# changing data type of autogenerated column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that auto generates columns...
The problem is, the data type are all imageurl.

when the gridview populates, the url is in label format.

I could define them as templatefield which works, but the requirement is to auto generate.

I read on MSDN of this, but i dont know how to proceed from there

```
private void BUChecker_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter this on its `TemplateFields`. See `GridView` controls'.
see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288031.aspx) for your reference.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx is a shorter resource that could be useful along with the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `RowDataBound` as follows **In case you don't want to use template field**

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //find your cell suppose it is Cell 0
       string imgUrl=e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
       Image img = new Imge();
       img.ImageUrl =imgUrl;
       e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(img);

    }
}
```